# Java Smart Card - Reading Scosta Smart Card

Tags: java, android, macos, smartcard, scosta

I am trying to read Indian Governments Standard 'Scosta' smart card through java **smartcardio**
the code I am using is

```
package com.example.smartcardreader;

import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.ATR;
import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

public class SmartCardReader {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            // show the list of available terminals
            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();

            List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

            System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

            // get the first terminal
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

            // establish a connection with the card
            Card card = terminal.connect("*");
            System.out.println("card: " + card);

            // get the ATR
            ATR atr = card.getATR();
            byte[] baAtr = atr.getBytes();

            System.out.print("ATR = 0x");
            for(int i = 0; i < baAtr.length; i++ ){
                System.out.printf("%02X ",baAtr[i]);
            }

            CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
            byte[] cmdApduGetCardUid = new byte[]{
                        (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};

            ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(
                                                new CommandAPDU(cmdApduGetCardUid));

            if(respApdu.getSW1() == 0x90 && respApdu.getSW2() == 0x00){

                byte[] baCardUid = respApdu.getData();

                System.out.print("Card UID = 0x");
                for(int i = 0; i < baCardUid.length; i++ ){
                    System.out.printf("%02X ", baCardUid [i]);
                }
            }

        card.disconnect(false);

        } catch (CardException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

I am using eclipse IDE for development in Mac machine. When I run this code, it gives me exception as it is not able to read Terminals. I have got a USB Card Reader and have also inserted smart card into it. 
Could you please point out where exactly am I going wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try any other application if it is able to work with your reader? Maybe you just need to install the driver.

Comment: I tried the same code in Windows machine with Netbeans and its working. So the problem is with my environment. The USB driver is properly installed and it shows in the list of devices attached also. What should I do now ?

Comment: What versions of OS X and Java are you using?

Comment: OS X Version 10.9.2 and Java 7 Update 51

Answer (score 2):

It may be unrelated to your problem but package javax.smartcardio seems to be seriously broken on Mac OS X with 64-bit version of java7. You can find more information in this [blog post](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.sk/2013/03/oracle-javaxsmartcardio-failures.html) and this [bug report](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4865737?tstart=90). You can also take a look at open source project [jnasmartcardio](https://github.com/jnasmartcardio/jnasmartcardio) that tries to solve the issues of javax.smartcardio package.